# Add VS Code to default context menu when right-clicking

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11, context-menu

In Windows Explorer, when I select a directory and right click on it, it opens a context menu. However, to open the directory in VS Code as a new project, I have to click on `Show more options`, then click the button at the bottom. Is there a way I can add the button to the original context menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're working on it, and you can track issue [204696](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/204696):

- While it's not yet on the Stable release, it's working on the Insider release; so far, it's quite stable despite some issue regarding this that keeps popping up on their GitHub